# CSS Padding from floated div

Tags: html, css, css-float

After solving my last problem with CSS `position` a new one came up.

[Live Demo](http://adamlisik.co.uk/kantor2)

Now I can't get any space between the `<table>'s` and the div with class `hr`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `div` is dimensionless so you need to add some "volume" to it to achieve spacing with the content above it. You can accomplish this by adding some height using CSS to the `hr` class.

Do like this:

```
.hr {
  height: 20px; /* set this # to whatever you'd like */
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `border-bottom` instead of top, specify the required `height`, and add some content (like `&nbsp;`) inside the "hr" div.

In fact, if you change the border top to bottom, you immediatley get the required spacing, but using the other option would be a bit clearer.